# If the blue Taoist kills a ghost that blocks his ability to seek help and fight in the same turn, can he then seek help from a villager?

Tags: ghost-stories

The blue Taoist has the ability to request help from a villager and fight a ghost in the same turn.  If this ability is blocked by a ghost, but then that ghost is killed by him, can he follow up in the same turn and request help immediately since his power is now unblocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

Under Taoist Powers on page 8 of [the rulebook](http://rprod.com/uploads/GS_RULES_US_ver1_3-web.pdf):

> It may happen that a Taoist loses his power because of a ghost
>   ability. He can recover it as soon as the responsible ghost is removed
>   from his board.

And the blue Taoist's Heavenly Gust Ability on the next page reads:

> The blue Taoist can act in a heartbeat.
>   He may request villager’s help AND attempt an exorcism in the same turn, in any order.

So you can definitely exorcise a ghost, unlocking your power, and then get a Villager's help in the same turn.